# Kernel Filter size and sampling frequency

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, signal-processing, spatio-temporal

I was wondering if I could understand the relationship between kernel size and sampling frequency. I was reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.08024.pdf) paper and on Pg 6-7 ("In block-1" section), I read that kernel size of 64 is half the size of sampling frequency (128 Hz). I don't understand how the kernel size is related to sampling rate and over that, how kernel related to time?

I also don't understand this part in the same section:

> Setting the length of the temporal kernel at half the sampling rate
> allows for capturing frequency information at 2Hz and above.

If somehow kernel size is 64Hz, then shouldn't the frequencies detected be < 32 Hz?

Comment: This might help from dsp [Nyquist Frequency and Window Length](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74895/nyquist-frequency-and-window-length)

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: @msuzen, you think this is what the paper is talking about?
https://support.ircam.fr/docs/AudioSculpt/3.0/co/Window%20Size.html#:~:text=A%20window%20size%20is%20expressed,its%20duration%20of%20frequency%20resolution.

Comment: Yes, window size and sampling frequencies are closely related, i.e, temporal convolution length.

Comment: Hi. Can you tell me why it mentions that the window size needs to be 5 times longer than the signal period? Is it something proven or is there any theory behind this?

Comment: Due to [Nyquist rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate).

Comment: But that has got to do with the frequency of the signal and it varries. So how did we get the constant factor of 5?

Comment: It is for that specific example. Idea is that we could capture the signal within Nyquist rate. Because window size restricts the frequencies to capture.

Comment: I do get that window size is somewhat synonymous with the number of samples we collect within a time frame. But factor 5 is being used for different frequencies there. So how is it for one specific example?